# Laravel move uploaded file

Tags: image, laravel, upload

It is working good for full path like this

```
$file=$request->file('file');
$file->move('C:\xampp\htdocs\modo\images',$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

But i cant understand why it doesnt for root folder path :

```
$file->move('\modo\images',$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use `base_path()` method. This method returns the fully qualified path to the project root:

So in your case try the below code:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$file->move(base_path('\modo\images'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

and if you want to return the public directory then use:

```
$path = public_path();
```

For more info read [Laravel helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-base-path)

Comment: if i want to save path of that moved file how can i do that

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it this way:

```
$file->move(base_path('\modo\images'),$file->getClientOriginalName());
```