# Store multiple image paths into database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I've form in my website. Out of many fields, there is one  field that let users allow to upload multiple images. I want to save the path for all images into database so that I can show them back on blade file.
I can upload images and images are stored into my local storage but the issue I get only one path and that is saved into database.

I want to store all paths separately into database so that I could access them for Blade. How can I do that?

Blade

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('form.multiStepStore')}}">
   @csrf
   <input type="file" class="form-control" name="photos[]" multiple />
......
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('photos')) {
        $allowedfileExtension = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];
        $files = $request->file('photos');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filepath = $filename.'.'.$extension;
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
        }
    $store_seller = new Sellers();
    $store_seller->img_path = $filepath;

    dd($filepath); //Returns only one path out of let's say 3 images
    }
}
```

Laravel 7. PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array :

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
    $filepath = array(); // $filepath is now an array
    if($request->hasFile('photos')) {
        $allowedfileExtension = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];
        $files = $request->file('photos');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = $filename.'.'.$extension;
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
            $filepath[] = $path; // add new image to array
        }
    $store_seller = new Sellers();
    $store_seller->img_path = $filepath;

    dd($filepath); //Returns array with 3 images
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not properly working. I again uploaded 3 files. It only returns 2 paths with the same name. 
One of the uploaded file was gmail-logo.png. 
After dd($filepath); it returns the same name but for 2 times.

Comment: @Shaan check now, it will work. The mistake was there was a variable name `filepath`, it makes this array to a variable. So I renamed it to `path`

Comment: I' m seeing all uploaded images into array now that's good. 
Last step, what If I want to store them into database? 
I tried implode function but it's giving me error.

Comment: @Shaan if you want to store the image name only,  then do it under foreach

Comment: One question, Is there any purpose of getting file extension. I mean it's look weird when it saves the file name into my storage like "logo.png.png" ?

Comment: @Shaan You are using Storage Put method, I suggest you to use move method, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694822/4575350

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
    {
        $images[]= Null; // $images array
        if($request->hasFile('photos')) {
            $allowedfileExtension = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];
            $files = $request->file('photos');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filepath = $filename.'.'.$extension;
                Storage::disk('local')->put($filename.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
                array_push($images, $filepath);  
            }
            $store_seller = new Sellers();
            $store_seller->img_path = $filepath;
    
        dd($images); //It will returns array with 3 images.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, we are very close. There are only 2 issues. Why I' m getting [0] index. Also, when I tried to implode the array. It returns error. 
How would I implode the array and store values into variable as string ?

Comment: @Shaan What type of error message you are getting on the implode function run?

Comment: @Shaan Try with this: $string = implode(',', $images[0]);

Comment: The only issue with your suggested code is that It returns 0 index and on upload 3 images, we see the array of 4 values not 3. 
Other that that your code is working :) ..

See the above answer of  #STA

Comment: If somewhere my code helped you then, Please upvote my answer.

Comment: If you could find out the solution for eliminating 0 index then i will definitely upvote for you. Otherwise, other people would get frustrated in eliminating that 0 index. :)